# How can I access/process content within TensorFlow Datasets?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am working with the [cnn_dailymail](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/datasets#cnn_dailymail) dataset which is part of the [TensorFlow Datasets](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/datasets). 
I access it as follows:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
data, info = tfds.load('cnn_dailymail', with_info=True)
train_data, test_data = data['train'], data['test']
```

To extract a single example from the dataset I use:

```
cnn_ex, = train_data.take(1)
cnn_ex['highlights'].numpy()
```

This will return a string similar to this: `"emma monaghan, 27, from glasgow, used to weigh 18st 5lbs ."`. I would like to apply some pre-processing steps to this dataset so I can use it as an input into a deep learning algorithm. The example above should look like this after preprocessing: `"<start> emma monaghan, 27, from glasgow, used to weigh 18st 5lbs . <end>"`.

Is there a way to access and pre-process all the text (within *train_data*) at once without having to apply the `take()` function multiple times? For example converting the TensorFlow Dataset into a numpy array would already help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `dataset.map()` to apply transformations to your data. For example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

data, info = tfds.load('cnn_dailymail', with_info=True)
dataset_train, dataset_test = data['train'], data['test']

def map_fn(x, start=tf.constant('<start>'), end=tf.constant('<end>')):
    strings = [start, x['highlights'], end]
    x['highlights'] = tf.strings.join(strings, separator=' ')
    return x

dataset_train = dataset_train.map(map_fn) # <-- apply transformation for the whole data
elem,  = dataset_train.take(1)
print(elem['highlights'].numpy())
# b'<start> arthur potts dawson: british ... <end>'
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your particular objective. Maybe `tfds.as_numpy()` is what you're looking for. You can apply it to `train_data` to get a generator_object. You can iterate over it directly, or apply any map function

```
train_data = train_data.map(map_func)
for i in tfds.as_numpy(train_data):
    print(i)
    ...
```